# Disappearing Bookmarks in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

How can I fix my Bookmarks? I use FireFox on Windows 8. One day half of my bookmarks were gone, and now I can't add any. I was not able to restore them from a previous day.

Answer (score 0):

In my Firefox profile folder I see a folder `bookmarkbackups`. Inside there are json files with backups of your bookmarks. Try to import the latest file again.